# Strict Mode Issue with Binding Arguments

Tags: javascript, arguments, strict

I have an issue with running a test on my files. Would love if someone more experienced could help me out here.

the following code gives me this error:

error  Parsing error: Binding arguments in strict mode

```
return (...arguments) => {
  if (something){
    return [something]
  }
```

Answer (score 5):

[`arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) is a special variable.

Use a different name.

```
function (...args) {
```